# How to iterate through each row in an excel workbook with openpyxl (how to solve infinite loop issue)?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an excel file that has some personal information in it. I am trying to get this information for each row in the excel file and do various kinds of sorting and re-assigning. My first step is to try to extract the information fro the workbook and store it in a dictionary of lists. My program ends up in an infinite loop. What is my mistake?

Here is the code I tried:

```py
import openpyxl

file = openpyxl.load_workbook("peopleList.xlsx")
sheet = file.active

person = {}
people = []

reader = 1

while sheet["A" + str(reader)].value != "":
    person["name"] = sheet["A" + str(reader)].value
    person["gender"] = sheet["B" + str(reader)].value
    person["school"] = sheet["C" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch1"] = sheet["D" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch2"] = sheet["E" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch3"] = sheet["F" + str(reader)].value
    people.append(person)
    person = {}

print(people)
```

Comment: `for row in sheet:…`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error in your condition. In the while statement you are only checking if there is a value in "A1". Since there is always a value there the loop in infinite. This works

```
import openpyxl

file = openpyxl.load_workbook('peopleList.xlsx')
sheet = file.active

person = {}
people = []


for reader in np.arange(1,len(sheet['A'])+1):
    person["name"] = sheet["A" + str(reader)].value
    person["gender"] = sheet["B" + str(reader)].value
    person["school"] = sheet["C" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch1"] = sheet["D" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch2"] = sheet["E" + str(reader)].value
    person["ch3"] = sheet["F" + str(reader)].value
    people.append(person)
    person = {}

print(people)
```

This is the important line:

```
for reader in np.arange(1,len(sheet['A'])+1):
```

It could be done using a while statement as well, but you are much less likely to get an infinite loop in a for loop, so I find them more explicit in a lot of cases. What I am doing here is counting the length of column A (assuming that it is the same as other columns, and then interating through a list of the numbers `[1,2,3,...,len(A)]` by creating that list with `np.arange(len(A))`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I forgot to add reader++ to the end of my while loop. Thank you have a nice day

Comment: Yes, that way is equivalent. If that answered your question consider checking it as answered. Since you are new to SO consider looking at this: [What do do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: No need for numpy here.